# Add Vertical Line ("Link") In between two items in ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

I have a ListView in which I created my own itemtemplate. The itemtemplate will simply look like a square with a colored border and inside will display very simple text. What I'd like to accomplish is to place a vertical line in between each item(listviewitem) to give it a look that they are "Linked" vertically. Right now I made a stackpanel but the problem is if you select the item it also selects the line. I want to make it look as if the line is not part of the listboxitem. Any ideas how i could go about designing this? To me a canvas seems to order but I didn't have any luck.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Margin="2">
            <Line StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" Y1="0" Y2="20" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                <Line.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstRow}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Line.Style>
            </Line>

            <Border x:Name="UnitBorder" Style="{StaticResource UnitBorderStyle}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UnitLandNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>

            <Line StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" Y1="0" Y2="20" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemTemplate` can just help you change the `ContentPresenter` layout. The whole `ContentPresenter` is always highlighted when selected. So it's hard to use it achieving what you want. To solve this we can use a custom `ControlTemplate` applied on `ListViewItem` instead. Here's an example of doing so:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="Template"> 
       <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
           <Grid>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               <RowDefinition/>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Line StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" Y1="0" Y2="20" Stroke="Black" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,1,0,0">
                   <Line.Style>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
                       <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
                       <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirstRow}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                         </DataTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>
                   </Line.Style>
             </Line>
             <Border Name="c"  Grid.Row="1">                                          
               <ContentPresenter/>
             </Border>
             <Line StrokeThickness="3" X1="0" Y1="0" Y2="20" Stroke="Black" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2"  Margin="15,0,0,1"/>
           </Grid>
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
               <Setter TargetName="c" Property="Background" 
                       Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
               <Setter TargetName="c" Property="TextElement.Foreground" 
                       Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
         </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
   </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

We divide the `ListViewItem` into 3 rows. The 2nd row (middle row) is of course the `ContentPresenter` which will be highlighted when selected. The 1st and 3rd rows are places for the connecting `Line`s. This `ListView` will lose some fairly skinned default look and feel. However you can try customizing it more (even better than the default).